# running pl/sql Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1issing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

Tags: oracle, plsql, jdeveloper

I have this procedure

```
PROCEDURE P_OBTENER_PLANES(PLANES OUT PLAN_SET) IS 

    BEGIN
    SELECT PLAN_T(A.SECUENCIAL)
    BULK COLLECT INTO PLANES
    FROM RECLAMACION A
    WHERE A.ANO = 2011;
END;
```

and I am trying to run it on JDeveloper with this code

```
DECLARE
    PLANES DBAPER.PLAN_SET;

    BEGIN

        PKG_EDC.P_OBTENER_PLANES(
        PLANES => PLANES
        );

    :PLANES := PLANES;

END;
```

I am getting

> Connecting to the database RERSERVAS_DEV.
>
> Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
>
> Process exited.
>
> Disconnecting from the database RERSERVAS_DEV.

PLAN_SET is a TABLE TYPE OF PLAN_T which only have an attribute number.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a different name for the parameter's argument than the parameter's name :

```
DECLARE
    v_PLANES DBAPER.PLAN_SET;
BEGIN

        PKG_EDC.P_OBTENER_PLANES(
        PLANES => v_PLANES
        );
END;
```

Comment: thanks, I tried your answer. 
If I skip the line

    :PLANES := PLANES

it has no error. But when I add that line to see the variable result on the Output Variable tab the execution crashes.

Comment: @eslamb you're welcome. You have to define `:PLANES`somewhere before `:PLANES := v_PLANES` assignment.